# Flutter Visual Studio - develop for Windows

Tags: windows, flutter, visual-studio, dart, desktop-application

There is a warning when I use flutter doctor :
Visual Studio - develop for Windows
X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

What does it mean ? i didnt find the installation component !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's basically saying that if you want to develop your flutter app for windows
you will need to install `Visual Studio 2022` and while installing Visual Studio 2022 you will need to download this: `Desktop development with C++`

Also you have to install the third link in this: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

You could also get `Desktop development with C++` tool after installing visual studio and then navigating to tool -> Get tools and features -> Desktop development with C++

[image]

Comment: Can I use Visual Studio **Code** instead?

Comment: @JavierLorenzo VS Code depends on Visual Studio workloads be able to build different kinds of apps such as desktop apps for window