# Unable to Run Desktop App using Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, window

I want to run my window application in flutter using android studio but I face this error
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
Exception: Unable to find suitable Visual Studio toolchain. Please run `flutter doctor` for more details.

I am unable run this I try a lot of things

Answer (score 0):

> Visual Studio 2022 to debug and compile native C++ Windows code. Make
> sure to install the Desktop development with C++ workload. This
> enables building Windows app including all of its default components.
> Visual Studio is an IDE separate from Visual Studio Code.

To facilitate the development of Flutter applications on Windows, it is essential to set up [Visual Studio 2022](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/de/downloads) for debugging and compiling native C++ Windows code. Ensure the installation of the `Desktop development with C++` workload, as this encompasses the essential components for building Windows applications.

Install Visual Studio from [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/de/downloads) and tick the checkbox for the `Desktop development with C++` workload during installation.

See the [docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows/desktop) for more info on how to get started.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `flutter doctor` you will get a recommendation to install Visual Studio. This is necessary for the development of Windows. You can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71019320/flutter-visual-studio-develop-for-windows) link for more information